# Adding id automatically on adding products to array

Tags: angular

I am trying to build an ec-ommerce website so the issue i am facing is that when in my form i am entering my values then on clicking the save button my values are being adding in an empty array which is declared in my services but i  also want to add id automatically to each product when it gets added to the array in the  services .How do i do that ?

html file

```
 <div class="col-md-5">
 <form (ngSubmit)="onsubmit()" #f="ngForm">
  <div class="md-form form-group mt-5">
 <input mdbInput type="text" class="form-control" 
 id="formGroupExampleInputMD" placeholder="Title"
 ngModel name="title" required #title="ngModel"
 >
 </div>

 <div class="md-form form-group mt-5">
<input mdbInput type="text" class="form-control" 
id="formGroupExampleInput2MD" placeholder="Price"
ngModel name="price" required #price="ngModel">
</div>

<div class="md-form form-group mt-5">
<select class="browser-default custom-select"
ngModel name="select" required #select="ngModel">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option *ngFor="let c of category|async" [value]="c.$key"> . 
{{c.name}}</option>
</select>

<div class="md-form form-group mt-5">
  <input mdbInput type="text" class="form-control" 
id="formGroupExampleInput2MD" placeholder="imageurl"
  ngModel name="imageurl" required #imageurl="ngModel"
  >
</div>
</div>

<button type="submit" mdbBtn color="primary" 
mdbWavesEffect>Save</button>


</form>

</div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryserviceService } from 
'src/app/sevices/categoryservice.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
selector: 'app-newproducts',
templateUrl: './newproducts.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./newproducts.component.scss']
})
export class NewproductsComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('f') form:NgForm
category
constructor(private ctservice:CategoryserviceService) { 

}

ngOnInit() {




 }
 onsubmit(){
// console.log(this.form.value)
this.ctservice.addtocards(this.form.value)

}



}
```

service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategoryserviceService {
cards:any[]=[]

constructor() { 


}


addtocards(values){
this.cards.push(values)
console.log(this.cards)
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add some unique id to each item, you can make use of the length of the **cards** array.

```
addtocards(values){
values['id'] = this.cards.length;
this.cards.push(values)
console.log(this.cards)
}
```

So, initially the length is 0. So, it becomes the id for the first product.

For **nth** product, the id would be **n - 1**